# large data in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developing a **Rails** app. I would like to use an array to hold **2,000,000 data**, then insert the data into database like following:

```
large_data = Get_data_Method() #get 2,000,000 raw data

all_values = Array.new

large_data.each{ |data|

    all_values << data[1] #e.g. data[1] has the format "(2,'john','2002-09-12')"

}

sql="INSERT INTO cars (id,name,date) VALUES "+all_values.join(',')

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

When I run the code, it takes a long long time at the point of `large_data.each{...}` . Actually I am now still waiting for it to finish(it has been running for 1 hour already still not finish the `large_data.each{...}` part).

Is it because of the number of elements is too large for the ruby array that the array can not hold **2,000,000** elements ?  or ruby array can hold that much elements and it is reasonable to wait this long?

Since I would like to use **bulk insertion** in SQL to speed up the large data insertion time in mysql database, so I would like to use only one `INSERT INTO` statement, that's why I did the above thing. If this is a bad design, can you recommand me a better way?

Comment: a minor question: do you leave blank lines between all lines of code?

Comment: Where do you get this data from? Why are you moving it from `large_data` to `all_values`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes:

Don't use the pattern "empty array + each + push", use [Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

```
all_values = large_data.map { |data| data[1] }
```

Is it possible to write `get_data` to return items lazily? if the answer is yes, check [enumerators](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html) and use them to do batched inserts into the database instead of puting all objects at once. Something like this:

```
def get_data
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    yielder.yield some_item
    yielder.yield another_item
    # yield all items.
  end
end

get_data.each_slice(1000) do |data|
  # insert those 1000 elements into the database
end
```

That said, there're projects for doing efficient bulk insertions, check [ar-extensions](http://www.igvita.com/2007/07/11/efficient-updates-data-import-in-rails/) and [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) for Rails >= 3.

Comment: Could you please be more detailed with using map in my case? and why map is better, and your 2nd link is broken.

Comment: edited with more examples. I guess you see why map is better, it's designed for this very task, processing single elements in lists, it's one of the most basic abstractions of functional programming: http://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming

Comment: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import is the best way I know of to do bulk importing of data, when using Rails >= 3.

Answer (score 1):

An array of 2m items is never going to be the easyist thing to manage, have you taken a look at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), this is a database which can be accessed just like an array and could be the answer to your issues.

An easy fix would be to split your inserts into blocks of 1000, that would make the whole process more manageable.